# Xquery/eXist-db - iterating over a collection +/- 3 positions from current document

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In eXist-db I have hundreds of documents in `/db/apps/foo/resources/documents` like so:

```
...
BNF9992-J305-1.xml
BNF9992-J305-5.xml
BNF9992-J308-9.xml
BNF9992-J310-8.xml
BNF9992-J311-1.xml
BNF9992-J312-6.xml
BNF9992-J312-7.xml
BNF9992-J315-9.xml
BNF9992-J316-2.xml
BNF9992-J317-2.xml
BNF9992-J319-3.xml
...
```

Imagine I want to present to the user a list of 3 documents appearing before and after a specific document (based on alpha-numeric sort). So, my 'current document' is  `BNF9992-J312-7.xml`, and I want to show the user something like:

```
BNF9992-J310-8.xml
BNF9992-J311-1.xml
BNF9992-J312-6.xml
BNF9992-J312-7.xml (current document)
BNF9992-J315-9.xml
BNF9992-J316-2.xml
BNF9992-J317-2.xml
```

Is there a function/method in Xquery 3.1 for iterating up/down a list of documents once they've been retrieved. The most I've been able to do is a simple retrieval of document names from a collection:

```
 for $resource in collection("/db/apps/foo/resources/documents")
 let $uri := base-uri($resource)
 return util:unescape-uri(replace($uri, ".+/(.+)$","$1"), "UTF-8")
```

But I don't know how to iterate up and down the list from a given document.

Perhaps writing the list into nodes and applying a formula to node ordinals?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were a list of strings $list, and the "current string" is $s, then I would do

```
let $i := index-of($list, $s)
return subsequence($list, $i - 3, 7)
```

I'm not sure whether the fact that you have a list of documents (rather than strings) changes this.

Comment: To get the list of strings that @jbrehr needs you can do `let $list := xmldb:get-child-resources("/db/apps/foo/resources/documents")`

Comment: If I only wanted .xml documents beginning with "abc", where would I add that to restrict `$list`? I tried adding  `starts-with()` but it threw an error about treating string as node.

Comment: You can always add a filter, e.g. `let $filteredList := $list[starts-with(., 'abc')]`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay, I was using the `starts-with()` function wrong

Comment: To ensure a consistent ordering, you might need to sort the list - see the `sort()` function or use a FLWOR with an `order by` clause.

Comment: I interpreted the phrase "(based on an alphanumeric sort)" and the fact that the sample input was sorted as an indication that we could assume the input is already sorted. I'm not very good at interpreting imprecise requirements though I do think that the more time I spend on StackOverflow, the better I get at it.